# Flutter onClosing callback for showModalBottomSheet

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `showModalBottomSheet` like the below, which I understand to inherit from `BottomSheet` (right?)

```
      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 260.0,
            child: Text('I am text')
          );
        },
      );
```

What I want to do:

I want to know (listen) when the modal is being closed, and act on it.

I've seen this `onClosing` callback: 
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomSheet/onClosing.html

How can I have a listener attached to the `showModalBottomSheet`, and then act accordingly when it fires?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Perhaps it's not the best solution, but showModalBottomSheet return a "Future" so you can used it.

For example:

```
void _showModal() {
    Future<void> future = showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(height: 260.0, child: Text('I am text'));
      },
    );
    future.then((void value) => _closeModal(value));
}
void _closeModal(void value) {
    print('modal closed');
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I try this approach: `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'then' was called on null.`

Answer (score 154):

You can also achieve it by use of `whenComplete` function of `showModalBottomSheet`.

Let's see below code

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 260.0,
            child: Text('I am text')
        );
      },
).whenComplete(() {
  print('Hey there, I\'m calling after hide bottomSheet');
});
```

Comment: Note that `whenComplete()` fires as soon as the close action begins -- the widget tree has not yet been torn down yet (so you can't call `dispose()` methods in here for controllers, etc.) -- put only `StatefulWidget` instances in a bottom sheet, and override `dispose()`, if you want to run code when the widget tree is torn down after the close action is complete.

Comment: Lifesaver!  After several hours of "notifyListeners()", "consumer", calling a refresh method in parent... this worked!  Thank you.

Answer (score 61):

#### Using async / await on showModalBottomSheet() close

You can do this with async / await instead of callbacks.

As per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html), showModalBottomSheet()

> Returns a Future that resolves to the value (if any) that was passed to Navigator.pop when the modal bottom sheet was closed.

This means that we can "await" the `showModelBottomSheet()` to complete, and then use the value returned by the `Navigator.pop()` function used to close the sheet.

Because this is "waiting" for the sheet to be closed, your next function won't run until it's closed. In this example, we just call the `print()` function, but that could be any function you need. No callbacks are necessary in this case.

**Tip:** if it's critical that the user tap a "save and close" button to close the bottom sheet (instead of just tapping outside of it), you should use `isDismissible: false` on the sheet.

In this example, we expect the sheet to return a string when it's closed.

#### Example Button To Open The showModalBottomSheet()

```
  FlatButton(
    child: Text("Show Bottom Sheet"),
    onPressed: () async {
      print("Showing bottom sheet...");
      String test = await showModalBottomSheet<String>(
        context: context,
        isDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) => Widget(),
      );
      print("Modal sheet closed with value: " + test);
    },
  ),
```

#### Example Button To Close The sheet, inside Widget()

```
FlatButton(
  child: Text("Save and Close"),
  onPressed: () {
    print("Closing sheet.");
    Navigator.pop(context, "This string will be passed back to the parent",);
  },
),
```

#### Example Log Outputs

```
flutter: Showing bottom sheet...
flutter: Closing sheet.
flutter: Modal sheet closed with value: This string will be passed back to the parent
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it explains how to use `showModalBottomSheet()` very well and using async / await is more elegant than callbacks.

Answer (score 12):

This is tested and verified on **28-01-2021**

```
showBottomSheet(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Container(//your sheet code here);      
  },
).closed.whenComplete(() {
 //do whatever you want after closing the bottom sheet
});
```

Comment: This is the easiest method for showBottomSheet I found, for people using showModalBottomSheet  ".closed" will not be available, but still they can use showModalBottomSheet().whenComplete(); instead. Happy coding :)

Comment: is it possible to return a value from the widget?

Comment: @chitgoks elaborate a little more?

Comment: i meant when the modalbottomsheet is closed to pass a value to it ao it can be used in whenComplete. but there seems to be no feature for this.

Answer (score 6):

showBottomSheet does not return a future, now it returns a PersistentBottomSheetController

```
  var _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  PersistentBottomSheetController persistentBottomSheetController;
```

```
 persistentBottomSheetController = _scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet<void>(
    (context)=>Container(

    )
 );
```

```
 persistentBottomSheetController.closed.then(_closeModal);
```

```
  void _closeModal(void value) {
    print('modal closed');
  }
```

Comment: this is correct but it never gets the value passed back from the navigator you can read more here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66837

Answer (score 6):

wrapper Container in `WillPopScope` widget

```dart
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () aysnc{
              // listener dismiss
              return true;
            }
            child : Container(
              height: 260.0,
              child: Text('I am text')
            ));
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 4):

I personally think the accepted answer is not as sleek as it can be. A wiser idea is to do it native Dart way without any extra complexity:

```
() async {
      final result = await showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (_) =>

      );
}
```

It also works with `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()`. `result` variable value in my case is defined by the value you pass back on `Navigator.of(context).pop({value})`. You can return any kind of object and then make a simple if statement to make sure data is the one you want:

```
if(result != null && result == true) { ... }
```

Comment: I would be really interested in why this was downvoted twice. For me this seems like the cleanest approach of them all. But I'm new to Dart and Flutter so would really like to understand if there is something wrong here.

Comment: @Hardcore_Graverobber This IS the most idiomatic way to do it in Dart. I really don't know why my answer has -2 rep :D

Comment: I don't know whether the `Future` returned by `showModalBottomSheet` can ever result in an error, but in general you are going to want to use the following instead, which acts more like `finally`, so it always runs, even if the `Future` resolves to an error: `showBottomSheet(...).whenComplete(() {...})`. For example, this would be important if in `whenComplete`, you need to dispose of a controller or listener.

Answer (score 2):

The showBottomSheet return a future.
Future<T?> showModalBottomSheet({});

So we can use a bool variable to check and know if the showBottomsheet is still open or not. For example, you have this code with this bool isStillOpen define in the top of your code,

```
Future<void> openShowBottomSheet(BuildContext  ctext) async {
// set your variable and open your bottomSheet
isStillOpen = true;
await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: ctext,
  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
      Container(height: 300, child: Center(child: Text('Hello'))));
isStillOpen = false;
```

// when the showBotom is close, the variable isStillOpen is set to false, so anywhere in your code you can check your variable to know if the bottomSheet is open or not.
}

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => SomeWidget(),
)..whenComplete(() {
  // do something on close
);
```

Although note that the widget tree is not torn down yet when `whenComplete` is called, so don't call `dispose()` methods in there for controllers, etc. (use StatefulWidgets inside the bottom sheet instead).

Answer (score 1):

```dart
() async {

   // Save the bottomsheet in a variable

   var bottomSheet = showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Container();
    );

   // Detect when it closes
   await bottomSheet.then((onValue) {
     print("value: $onValue");
   });

   // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**When the bottomsheet is closed and the *.whenComplete((){})* method is working and also *.then((void value){})* method also use**

> whenComplete method

```
_void() {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container();
        }).whenComplete(() {
      // call the function;
    });
  }
```

> then method

```
_void() {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container();
        }).then((value) {
     // call the function;
    });
  }
```