# Flutter - How to take an action when the bottom modal sheet is dismissed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a filters button. It's a container with a border, and inside are two icons in a row. All of this is wrapped in a gesture detector.

When the user taps the gesture detector, I am showing a bottom modal sheet. This all works. However, I want one of the icons to change depending on whether the user has the bottom modal sheet activated or not. How can I achieve this?

I think I can call setState once the button is tapped, BEFORE showing the modal bottom sheet. How can call setState again when the user taps out of it?

Thanks!

Is there an option to configure this in the showModalBottomSheet constructor?

Comment: can you share your code and image or video what you want to achieve?

Comment: You can use [`whenComplete()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592970/8244632) as answered here to listen to the closing event of the `BottomSheet`.

Answer (score 5):

As you did not post any code I'm guessing that you are using the method `showModalBottomSheet`.

This method has the following prototype:

```dart
Future<T?> showModalBottomSheet<T>({
  required BuildContext context,
  required WidgetBuilder builder,
  Color? backgroundColor,
  double? elevation,
  ShapeBorder? shape,
  Clip? clipBehavior,
  BoxConstraints? constraints,
  Color? barrierColor,
  bool isScrollControlled = false,
  bool useRootNavigator = false,
  bool isDismissible = true,
  bool enableDrag = true,
  RouteSettings? routeSettings,
  AnimationController? transitionAnimationController,
})
```

[source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)

As you can see it returns a `Future<T?>` type which means that you can apply `await`, `then` or `whenComplete` to the returned future operation. In your case using `whenComplete` might be the better option if you don't need any value from the bottom sheet.

### Example

```dart
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
).whenComplete(_onBottomSheetClosed);
```

```dart
void _onBottomSheetClosed() {
  print("Closed bottomsheet");
}
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2526bbc0f0420f5496065f60084ce4f2)

Comment: can you also pass data ?

Comment: always you can, Navigator.of(context).pop(passYourDataHere); @Aristidios

Answer (score 0):

I was searching how  to dismiss bottom sheet after navigation through it to a second screen , I found out that bottom sheet gets also added to navigation stack so ,
just use pushReplacement:

Navigator.pushReplacement(
context,PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: Page()));

hope this help someone.